# How to get Intellij Ultimate to deploy SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

My goal is to take my very simple "hello world" two-class SpringBoot app and deploy it on Tomcat and show a ThymeLeaf template. I'm compiling with JDK 17 with no errors.

No JAR or WAR (I've tried both, exploded and non-exploded) migrate to the Tomcat directories.

My question is:

**Where are the key areas to control deployment from either IntelliJ building methods to Maven settings?**

I never see any files migrating regardless of what settings I choose.

The `Deployments` tab is very confusing to me. I can't see any physical location specified in the settings to ensure things get where they need to be. I've gone through numerous tutorials and nothing causes files to be moved for SpringBoot. I get a `404` error for every output on localhost.

Thank you in advance.

My app:

````
@SpringBootApplication
public class MagicVisionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MagicVisionApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "home"})
    public String displayHomePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("username", "John Doe");
        return "home.html";
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the traditional deployment documentation part. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment
You need to create SpringBootServletInitializer and few more tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. My solution was in the Output Directory of the `Facets` and `Artifacts` creation areas. It has to point everything to the ROOT directory.

**Facets** need to output to the correct /WEB-INF/ directory inside the Tomcat you want to use. If you decide to change versions, you'll have to change your Facet output directory.

**Artifacts** need to be output to the proper /ROOT/ directory for your designated WAR file. The system will also create your app directory informing Tomcat of your overall URL mappings.

[image]
[image]